# Using `--cnf-line` to add `pygmentize` to `shell_escape_commands` ad hoc

Tags: shell-escape, texmf.cnf

I noticed the command-line flag `--cnf-line`, which can be used for `lualatex` (and related commands) and is described in its help page (`lualatex --help`) as follows (formatted for clarity):

```
--cnf-line=STRING    parse STRING as a configuration file line
```

Now, I was trying to make use of this flag to make the [`minted`](https://ctan.org/pkg/minted) package work without, as `--shell-escape` would, allowing *all* shell commands. However, the following (and several variations thereof, incl. removal of the quotation marks) consistently throws an error regarding `--shell-escape` being needed:

```sh
lualatex --cnf-line="shell_escape_commands=pygmentize" --shell-restricted root.tex
```

The `root.tex` file referred to above:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{javascript}
    let a = 3;
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

---

**NB**: I don't want to modify the local `texmf.cnf`, hence the desire for an ad hoc solution.

---

**Edit**: Given [@UlrikeFischer's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/714199/using-cnf-line-to-add-pygmentize-to-shell-escape-commands-ad-hoc#comment1775304_714199) about `minted` itself checking for `--shell-escape`, I suspect that my goal might be particularly difficult to achieve with this package. However, I tried to test the concept with a simpler example, and could still not get it to work:

```sh
latex --cnf-line="shell_escape_commands=echo" --shell-restricted root.tex
```

The `root.tex` file referenced above:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\immediate\write18{echo hello > hello.txt}
\end{document}
```

Meanwhile, if `--shell-restricted` is replaced by `--shell-escape`, it works as expected. Am I using these interfaces incorrectly, or is this a bug?

---

**Related**:

- [TUG changelog entry for `--cnf-line`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-890009.1.17)

Comment: well minted tests if shell-escape is activated, so it doesn't help if the command is in the restricted list. You could try to fool it with `\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}\makeatletter\def\pdf@shellescape{1}\makeatother` but that is untested.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do the trick — I'm getting the error `Package catchfile Error: File `root.w18' not found.`

Comment: `minted` doesn't use shell escape just for `pygmentize`.